# Splitting of voltage in a parallel circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

The circuit is here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bFF2H1-OnX9II05L8BUYdZJCZoIqXJVu/view?usp=sharing

[image: Circuit]

Let voltage at A, B, and C be Va, Vb, and Vc.

Is Va = Vb = Vc, 
or is it Va = Vb, Vc = Va + Vb?

Comment: Hi championrat. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voltages will be equal and you can see it ,if you apply Kirchoff's Loop law in this circuit which states that the algebraic sum of voltages for a closed loop series is equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage at A,B,C is same as it is a metallic wire.A metallic wire has same potential at all continuous points provided it is ideal(meaning zero resistance)

Comment: Actually it's not a "metallic" wire – it's an _ideal_ wire.